# Angular dependency injection performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services

Which of the following two cases do you think is better in terms of performance
(having many dependencies to inject in a service)?

```
app.service('randomService', function(dependency1, dependency2, ...) {
    //code
});
```

or

```
app.service('randomService', function($injector) {
    var service;
    this.svFct = function (entityType, idList, entityList) {
            switch (entityType) {
                    case 'product':
                        service = $injector.get('dependency1');
                        service.get({}, onSuccess, onError);
                        break;
                    case 'order':
                        service = $injector.get('dependency2');
                        service.get({}, onSuccess, onError);
                        break;
                    case 'actor':
                        service = $injector.get('dependency3');
                        service.get({}, onSuccess, onError);
                        break;
                     ...
                    }
    };
});
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question marked as dupe is about testing and `angular.mock.inject`, it has nothing to do with the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Performance impact of Angular injector is negligible. Services are singletons which are instantiated on first injection and retrieved from key/value storage on subsequent injections.

The comparison is incorrect since two snippets don't contain the same logic. `svFct` method can be called multiple times and will do `$injector.get(...)` on each call.

In first case there is one injector call. In second case there are multiple injector calls.